# Gather equations and tables side-by-side

Tags: math-mode, tabularx

How can I make both the table and the gather be on the same level. Is there a better way than tabularx?

```
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X|X}

    {\begin{gather*}
        C_{g|in} =C_{gn}+C_{gp}\\
        C_{int}=C_{outputnode}\\
        p=(C_{gate}/C_{inv})_{int}\\
        g=(C_{gate}/C_{inv})_{g}\\
        b=f/f_{on-path}\\
        H=BGF\\
        B=\prod_i b_i \tab
        G=\prod_i g_i\\
        F=C_L/C_{g,1}\\
        P=\sum_i p_i\\
        t_p=\sum_i tp_o(p_i+h_i/\gamma)
    \end{gather*}}

    &

    {\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}\hline
        Gate     & p          & g        \\\hline
        INV      & 1          & 1        \\
        NAND     & n          & (n+2)/3  \\
        NOR      & n          & (2n+1)/3 \\
        MUX      & 2n         & 2        \\
        XOR/XNOR & $n2^{n-1}$ & - \\\hline
    \end{tabular}}

\end{tabularx}
```

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  you probably want to specify that both elements should be top-aligned.  for `gather` that should be `[t]` after `\begin{gather}`.  and the table might benefit from spacing the lines farther apart; `\arraystretch` might help you there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two versions, with different alignments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\newcommand\tab{\quad}
\newcommand\tsub[1]{_{\textup{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\hspace*{\fill}%
$\begin{gathered}
  C_{g|\mathrm{in}}=C_{gn}+C_{gp}\\
  C\tsub{int}=C\tsub{outputnode}\\
  p=(C\tsub{gate}/C\tsub{inv})\tsub{int}\\
  g=(C\tsub{gate}/C\tsub{inv})_{g}\\
  b=f/f\tsub{on-path}\\
  H=BGF\\
  B=\prod_i b_i \tab
  G=\prod_i g_i\\
  F=C_L/C_{g,1}\\
  P=\sum_i p_i\\
  t_p=\sum_i tp_o(p_i+h_i/\gamma)
\end{gathered}$%
\hspace{\fill}%
\vrule
\hspace{\fill}%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
  Gate     & $p$        & $g$        \\
\hline
  INV      & $1$        & $1$        \\
  NAND     & $n$        & $(n+2)/3$  \\
  NOR      & $n$        & $(2n+1)/3$ \\
  MUX      & $2n$       & $2$        \\
  XOR/XNOR & $n2^{n-1}$ & - \\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
\hspace*{\fill}%

\end{center}

\begin{center}
\hspace*{\fill}%
$\begin{gathered}[t]
  C_{g|\mathrm{in}}=C_{gn}+C_{gp}\\
  C\tsub{int}=C\tsub{outputnode}\\
  p=(C\tsub{gate}/C\tsub{inv})\tsub{int}\\
  g=(C\tsub{gate}/C\tsub{inv})_{g}\\
  b=f/f\tsub{on-path}\\
  H=BGF\\
  B=\prod_i b_i \tab
  G=\prod_i g_i\\
  F=C_L/C_{g,1}\\
  P=\sum_i p_i\\
  t_p=\sum_i tp_o(p_i+h_i/\gamma)
\end{gathered}$%
\hspace{\fill}%
\vrule
\hspace{\fill}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|l|}
\firsthline
  Gate     & $p$        & $g$        \\
\hline
  INV      & $1$        & $1$        \\
  NAND     & $n$        & $(n+2)/3$  \\
  NOR      & $n$        & $(2n+1)/3$ \\
  MUX      & $2n$       & $2$        \\
  XOR/XNOR & $n2^{n-1}$ & - \\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
\hspace*{\fill}%

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Sorry, but I can't stand upright math symbols.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain to me how `\hspace{\fill}` works in the first example? Also what changes should be made if i'm working in a `\multicols` article?

Comment: @usfmohy There was no mention of two column typesetting in your question. In that case, I can see no other way than one above the other. The four `\hspace{\fill}` put equal spaces so the text width is filled up.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? I changed  `gather*` to `gathered` to remove  `\abovedisplayskip`  used the `[t]` optional argument for both `gathered` and `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools,}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X| >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
  $ \begin{gathered}[t]C_{g|in} =C_{gn}+C_{gp}\\
        C_{int}=C_{outputnode}\\
        p=(C_{gate}/C_{inv})_{int}\\
        g=(C_{gate}/C_{inv})_{g}\\
        b=f/f_{on-path}\\
        H=BGF\\
        B=\prod_i b_i \quad%\tab
        G=\prod_i g_i\\
        F=C_L/C_{g,1}\\
        P=\sum_i p_i\\
        t_p=\sum_i tp_o(p_i+h_i/\gamma)
    \end{gathered} $
    &
    \raisebox{0.7\baselineskip}{\begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|l|}\hline
        Gate & p & g \\\hline
        INV & 1 & 1 \\
        NAND & n & (n+2)/3 \\
        NOR & n & (2n+1)/3 \\
        MUX & 2n & 2 \\
        XOR/XNOR & $n2^{n-1}$ & - \\\hline
    \end{tabular}}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry why did you use raisebox instead and what are baselines? I'm always facing problems placing objects side-by-side.

Comment: The basel is where the bottom of a letter without descenders (say the letter m) is. I raised box by exactly 0.7\baselineskip because  otherwise, it is the top rule which is aligned with the base line. Here, you'll notice the bottom of the G in the second column is aligned with the *C* in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ r| l}
\arraycolsep=1.4pt  \def\arraystretch{1.5}
$\begin{array}[t]{@{} r l @{}}
  C_{g|in} &=C_{gn}+C_{gp}\\
  C_{int}  &=C_{outputnode}\\
        p  &=(C_{gate}/C_{inv})_{int}\\
        g  &=(C_{gate}/C_{inv})_{g}\\
        b  &=f/f_{on-path}\\
        H  &=BGF\\
        B  &=\prod_i b_i \quad G=\prod_i g_i\\
        F  &=C_L/C_{g,1}\\
        P  &=\sum_i p_i\\
        t_p&=\sum_i tp_o(p_i+h_i/\gamma)
\end{array}$ 
        &
\begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|l|}\firsthline
    Gate & p & g \\\hline
    INV & 1 & 1 \\
    NAND & n & (n+2)/3 \\
    NOR & n & (2n+1)/3 \\
    MUX & 2n & 2 \\
    XOR/XNOR & $n2^{n-1}$ & - \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you use `array` instead of `gather`? I'm trying to have a grasp of how alignment works not just the solution to this specific problem.